# Check device type via user_agent (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, user-agent

I want to know whether my users are browsing a page in my rails application with

- a tablet or
- a mobile device or
- a desktop computer

I digged through many different solutions. Here are my favorites:

1. The ua-parser gem: https://github.com/ua-parser/uap-ruby which seems to be very clean but unfortunately it always plots `Other` when I use `parsed_string.device` - I can detect the OS and browser with it very well.
2. Writing it from scratch

Writing from scratch ended up in sth like this:

```
if request.user_agent.downcase.match(/mobile|android|iphone|blackberry|iemobile|kindle/)
  @os = "mobile"
elsif request.user_agent.downcase.match(/ipad/)
  @os = "tablet"
elsif request.user_agent.downcase.match(/mac OS|windows/)
  @os = "desktop"
end
```

However, what I miss is a complete documentation of the user agent 'device' definitions.

For example:
What patterns do I need to look at if my user is browsing on a tablet/mobile device or desktop? I can't just guess and checking e.g. the ua-parser regex is not helping me either (very complicated): https://github.com/tobie/ua-parser/blob/master/regexes.yaml

Is there any simple solution to solve my problem?
How does google analytics do it? I tried to research but could not find it. They're also displaying devices (desktop/tablet/mobile).

Comment: give [browser](https://github.com/fnando/browser) a try. It is better than `ua-parser` in many ways

Comment: that looks promising, thank you

Answer (score 1):

The [browser gem](https://github.com/fnando/browser) has a [suggestion](https://github.com/fnando/browser/issues/311) to do this, but until that is added you could still use the gem to figure it out by using `browser.device?`

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking to do the 2nd option, because I need it as lean-n-mean as possible. There'se a lot of information in the User-Agent string, that I just don't need. And I don't want a function that tries to parse it all. Just simply: bot, desktop, tablet, mobile and other.

It's kind of a lot to read, but I'm looking for keywords using [this extensive list](https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/).

So far, the following keywords seems to work for me. It's regular expressons in php, but you'll get the idea.

```
//try to find crawlers
//  https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/software_type_specific/crawler/
if (preg_match('/(bot\/|spider|crawler|slurp|pinterest|favicon)/i', $userAgent) === 1)
  return ['type' => 'crawler'];

//try to find tablets
//  https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/hardware_type_specific/tablet/
//  https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/hardware_type_specific/ebook-reader/
if (preg_match('/(ipad| sm-t| gt-p| gt-n|wt19m-fi|nexus 7| silk\/|kindle| nook )/i', $userAgent) === 1)
  return ['type' => 'tablet'];

//try to find mobiles
//  https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/hardware_type_specific/mobile/
//  https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/hardware_type_specific/phone/
if (preg_match('/(android|iphone|mobile|opera mini|windows phone|blackberry|netfront)/i', $userAgent) === 1)
  return ['type' => 'mobile'];

//try to find desktops
//  https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/hardware_type_specific/computer/
if (preg_match('/(windows nt|macintosh|x11; linux|linux x86)/i', $userAgent) === 1)
  return ['type' => 'desktop'];

return ['type' => 'other'];
```